# I’m pretty sure this is a scam

Tags: scams, paypal, sugar-daddy

I had a ‘sugar daddy’ follow me on Instagram, he asked me to get another app to converse on there (so I did) and now he’s telling me I have to play a $100 fee to convert $5000USD to AUD. I’m 95% sure it’s a scam but I also can’t find any I formation about transfer fees on PayPal. It gets weirder though, he then told me he needed me to buy that much in bitcoin and verify that purchase, then he went on with ‘because it’s a business account the fees work differently’. What do I do?

Comment: The only real sugar daddy is the one you have sex with and take the cash from the counter before you leave. Any other sugar daddy is a scam.

Comment: Basically, any question that includes the phrase "online sugar daddy" can immediately be answered with "It's a scam."  The only question is going to be what kind -- straight larceny, blackmail, or using the victim to launder money would be the most common.

Comment: If you have to pay money to get money, it's a scam. Throw in sugar daddy and it's certain.

Answer (score 2):

95% sure it's a scam is probably being generous. Any time someone says, "I want to give you a bunch of money but to do it you first have to pay this fee", it's almost always a scam.

Suggest he just take the $100 out of the $5000 and give you $4900. If the offer was legitimate, then even if there was some fee that should take care of it. Sometimes scammers claim that they don't have the up front cash. But if he's offering you $5000 to be his sugar baby, presumably he has the cash. If not, it's a different kind of scam.

Comment: "almost" always? I've never read of anything that wasn't a scam when described in this manner. It's a sad statement of our society.

Comment: @fred_dot_u Yes, I'm just very reluctant to make absolute generalizations. Has there ever been a case in the history of the world where such a proposition was legitimate? Maybe. But I'm hard pressed to think of an example.

Comment: I wouldn't even make that suggestion in the second paragraph. There's absolutely no chance this is legitimate and it's much safer to just cut off contact and block them immediately.